# Is it possible to simulate 4G network in iPhone Simulator or device?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, reachability

I wanted to know whether my device is connected to Wi-Fi or 3G or 4G specifically.Currently I am using Apple [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) classes to check Internet Connection.
When I gave App for beta release to client it's showing connected network as Wi-Fi not 4G even though device is connected to 4G network.In my development location there is no 4G network to test.So is there any tool that can simulate 4G network?

Note:

1. I tried with Xcode tool Network Link Conditioner, but by this I am able to simulate only speed of the network but not the type of the network.
2. I tried with [CoreTelephony](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/index.html) framework also.But by using this I am getting incorrect results for iPad and iPhone.

**iPhone 5:**

1. Connected to Wi-FI with SIM getting CTRadioAccessTechnologyHSDPA
2. Connected to Wi-Fi without SIM getting NULL
3. Connected to 3G getting CTRadioAccessTechnologyHSDPA

**iPad:**

Connected to WI-FI but I am getting NULL

API returning NULL value when there is no SIM in device.

So Is there any valid way to know whether the  device(iPad and iPhone) is connected to Wi-FI or 3G or 4G.

Comment: The only possible solution to beta test your app on 3G and 4G is to use SIM on device. You can test it on Simulator.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability and check the `isReachableViaWWAN` property in the reachable block

Comment: @JayprakashDubey I am able to test 3G and Wi-Fi but not 4G because in my location there is no 4G service.

Comment: There should be no difference, in terms of indicated connection type, between 3G and 4G - Either you are connected by WiFi or via WWAN (3G/4G)

Comment: @Paulw11 Ya that's fine.Actually the problem is even when device is connected to 4G API is returning Reachable via Wi-FI instead of WWAN.

Comment: I wrote a little test app using the reachability library that I linked to and it correctly reports "Cellular" for a 4G connection on my iPad Air 2.

Comment: The same test app also reports "Cellular" for a 4G connection on my iPhone 6 (My phone has a different carrier and I wasn't in a 4G area for them an hour ago)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I replaced existing classes with [this](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) and tested in actual 4G device, it's working as expected.

Comment: I don't understand how apple doesn't have implemented a way to do this in 2022